# A good way to include non-localised values in Django templates

Tags: localization, django-templates

I need to pass decimal (floating point) values to Javascript in my Django template. The data is passed as `data-` elements, e.g.

```
{% for face in photo.face_set.all %}
    <span class="face-text" style="margin-left: 1em;"
        data-roi='{ "x":{{ face.x }}, "y":{{ face.y }}, "w":{{ face.w }}, "h":{{ face.h }} }'>
        {{ face.person.display_as }}<br>
    </span>
{% endfor %}
```

The obvious problem with this is that for locales with commas as a decimal separator, `{{face.(x,y,w,h)}}` are rendered e.g. as `1,234`, while data values should be given with a decimal point.

I know that `safe` and `unlocalize` can be used to prevent this behaviour, but it doesn't seem right: my code should probably somehow make distinction between displayed and code values, without explicitly formatting each individual value. What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would get all the "value" part of the data formatted in python, [converted to JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json) and passed to the template. I would then use javascript to [get back the data](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) and populate your HTML template.

Comment: Could you give an example? Do you mean separating HTML and data? This `data-` approach is really nice to have things encapsulated. But maybe it's actually not recommended...